# Update datatable columns with values from another datatable

Tags: r, datatable, assign

Consider the following two data.tables:

```
df1=data.table(a=1:3, b=4:6, c=7:9)
df2=data.table(a=c(T,F,T), c=c(F,F,T), d=c(T,F,F))
```

What is the best way to update columns `a` and `c` of `df1` with the corresponding values from `df2`?

`df1[,c("a","c"),with=FALSE]` and `df2[,c("a","c"),with=FALSE]` return the corresponding parts of each data.table;

but `df1[,c("a","c"),with=FALSE] <- df2[,c("a","c"),with=FALSE]` returns an error!

Comment: Note that you are trying to update a column with another of different type (integer vs logical).  If you intend `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as 0, then `df1 * df2` is enough

Comment: Also, you can use `set` `nm1 <- c("a", "c");
 for(j in nm1) set(df1, i = NULL, j = j, value = df1[[j]] * df2[[j]])`

Comment: You are right! Maybe I didn't provide a good example, but I am looking for a solution that works for any possible df2 values?

Comment: In that case, first you need to change the type of columns in 'df1' wiht the same type as 'df2' and then do the `set` `set(df1, i = NULL, j= j, value = df2[[j]])`

Comment: @akrun - `df1[, c("a","c") := df2[, c("a","c")]]` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
df2 <- tibble(a = c(T,F,T), c = c(F,F,T), d = c(T,F,F))

bind_cols(df1, df2) %>% 
  transmute(a = a1, b, c = c1)
```

This creates a table with all six columns and then the `transmute` call selects and renames the ones you're interested in.